# Smith normal form of a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modules

I want to find the Smith Normal form of the following matrix :
$$\left(\begin{matrix}2 &-4&-1\\0&2&3\\-3&8&3\end{matrix}\right)$$
We have, $$\left(\begin{matrix}2 &-4&-1\\0&2&3\\-3&8&3\end{matrix}\right)\to \left(\begin{matrix}2 &0&0\\0&2&6\\-3&2&3\end{matrix}\right)\to \left(\begin{matrix}2 &0&0\\0&2&0\\-3&2&-3\end{matrix}\right)\to \left(\begin{matrix}2 &0&0\\0&2&0\\0&2&-3\end{matrix}\right) \to \left(\begin{matrix}2 &0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&6\end{matrix}\right)$$

But determinant value mismatch. So somewhere the process is wrong ! I'm unable to find my mistake.

Edit:

We have, $$\left(\begin{matrix}2 &-4&-1\\0&2&3\\-3&8&3\end{matrix}\right)\to \left(\begin{matrix}-1 &0&0\\0&14&6\\0&20&3\end{matrix}\right)$$
Now, $$\left(\begin{matrix}14 & 6\\20 & 3\end{matrix} \right)\to \left(\begin{matrix}3 & 20\\6 & 14\end{matrix} \right)$$

From this step , how I can proceed ?

Comment: How did you try to find your mistake?

Comment: How does column $\pmatrix{0\\6\\3}$ arise in your second matrix?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown By $C_3'=2C_3+C_1$

Comment: So you **doubled** a column :-( @Topo

Comment: Looking at the latest edit, asking the same question again, how did you get $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 6 & 3 \end{bmatrix}^T$? does the determinant of the current matrix make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Smith form for integer matrices is obtained by applying the following elemantary transformations to rows (columns) of the matrix:

1) Multiply the row (column) by $-1$

2) Interchange (permute) two rows (columns)

3) multiply a row (column) by an integer and add the result to another row (column)

The Smith form of a matrix  $M$ of rank $\rho$ is a matrix with all elements equal to $0$ except the first  diagonal emements $\rho$ $M_{1,1}, \cdots , M_{\rho,\rho}$  which, in addition satisfy the divisibility property $M_{i,i} | M_{i+1,i+1}$, $i=1,\cdots,\rho-1$.

Elemantary transformations of type 3) above correspond to pre (post) multiplication with triangular matrices with  $1$s in the diagonal.

The mistake in the question is in the transformation which replaces the third column with $2$ times the third column plus the first column corresponds to multiplication with matrix

$\left[ 
\begin{matrix} 
1&0&1\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&2
\end{matrix}
\right]$

which clearly has determinant equal to $2$ and does not correspond to the allowed elemantary transformations leading to the Smith form.

The correct Smith form is

$
\left[ 
\begin{matrix} 
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&6
\end{matrix}
\right]$

and is obtained by applying transformations of types 1),2) and 3)  above as follows:

$\left[ 
\begin{matrix} 
2&-4&-1\\
0&2&3\\
-3&8&3
\end{matrix}
\right]
\sim
\left[ 
\begin{matrix} 
1&-4&2\\
-3&2&0\\
-3&8&-3
\end{matrix}
\right]
\sim
\left[ 
\begin{matrix} 
1&0&0\\
-3&-10&6\\
-3&-4&3
\end{matrix}
\right]
\sim
\left[ 
\begin{matrix} 
1&0&0\\
0&-10&6\\
0&-4&3
\end{matrix}
\right]
\sim
\left[ 
\begin{matrix} 
1&0&0\\
0&6&-4\\
0&3&-1
\end{matrix}
\right]
\sim
\left[ 
\begin{matrix} 
1&0&0\\
0&3&-1\\
0&6&-4\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
\sim
\left[ 
\begin{matrix} 
1&0&0\\
0&1&3\\
0&4&6\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
\sim
\left[ 
\begin{matrix} 
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&4&-6\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
\sim
\left[ 
\begin{matrix} 
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&6
\end{matrix}
\right]$

Comment: How you can get from 4th matrix to 5th matrix ?

Comment: add third column to second column and then swap them.